# Ruby - remove inherited methods

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to remove some of the inherited methods in Ruby? I mean, I can override it, but is there any other way?

```
Class ABC
end

a = ABC.new

puts a.id
```

Here, the method `id` is inherited from `Object` along with other methods like `tap`,`class`,`type` etc. I want to remove such methods.

**Edit:** I'm using Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: Refer my comment on Chowlett's answer ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes - `undef_method :foo` will prevent any calls to the method `foo` (contrasted with `remove_method :foo`, which removes the method from the child, but still passes through up the inheritance chain).

Once again, though, *why* do you want to remove things like `id`?

Comment: I'm using a class (sort of a DSL) that acts as a map to an xml (a well defined format, not deeply nested) and using method-missing to access the xml nodes. for example, if the xml has a node called "book", I'll access the node content using a.book. This method_missing is not getting triggered if the xml node has name(which I have no control over) like "id", "type" etc.  

Is there something wrong with removing these methods? I'm using that class only for this mapping, not for anything else. Are there any methods I shouldn't remove?

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes some sense, and feels like quite a nice solution (although I'd probably use an XML parsing library...). I think, so long as you leave the `__foo__` methods, you should be ok.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember that you can also "accept" this answer as "correct" by clicking the check-mark under the vote buttons.

Comment: Just note that if you undef a method name, you can never re-add a method with that name. The class just won't respond to it anymore even if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can always create a blank slate class to derive from:

```
class BlankSlate
  instance_methods.each do |m|
    undef_method(m) unless (m.match(/^__/))
  end
end
```

This should strip out all methods except for the internal ones that you're not supposed to mess with, like `__send__`.

Answer (score 2):

As tadman said you can make a BlankSlate object, or in ruby 1.9, there is the BasicObject class that has a bare minimum of methods.  A quick google search turned up this for further reading: http://www.humbug.in/docs/ruby-best-practices/I_sect13_d1e2654.html

It appears that Rails already has BlankSlate built in:   http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/BlankSlate

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Ruby 1.8.7